# Efficient DRY practice and Django instance in memory

Tags: python, django, orm, garbage-collection

Which of the following is best for following DRY principals
while not necessarily consuming system memory?

```
my_cart_id #this var could hold value or None

cart = Cart()
try:
    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=my_cart_id)
except Cart.DoesNotExist: 
    pass
except Exception as e: 
    MyExceptionHandler(e)
```

OR

```
try:
    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=my_cart_id)
except Cart.DoesNotExist: 
    cart = Cart()
except Exception as e: 
    ExceptionHandler(e)
    cart = Cart()
```

OR

```
cart = None
try:
    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=my_cart_id)
except Cart.DoesNotExist: 
    pass
except Exception as e: 
    ExceptionHandler(e)
finally:
    cart = cart if cart else Cart()
```

I prefer the first one, but which is best? The first case will often create empty cart instances. Does the memory get reclaimed if the variable is overwritten?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do here. What's the point of the extra exception handler? What other exceptions are you trying to catch?

Comment: Are you planning to save the new `Cart` if you create one? If so, this is a case for `get_or_create`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: In each case, the code will add some data, then save the cart. If `cart_id == None`, then using `get_or_create` would still be the proper use, correct? Created instances already start with 'id=None', correct?

Comment: I habitually add a default exception handler to catch things I just haven't thought of. In this case, is the `DoesNotExist` the only possible exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments!
[get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) appears to be the best solution.

```
try:
    cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(id=my_cart_id)
except Exception as e:
    ExceptionHandler(e)
    cart = Cart()

#do stuff
cart.save()
```

However, not sure if the `try` even necessary here.